# has_friendly_id not working with acts_as_paranoid model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, friendly-id, acts-as-paranoid

I am getting following error while adding a record in my Contact model.

```
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'john-doe' for key 'index_contacts_on_cached_slug': UPDATE `contacts` SET `cached_slug` = 'john-doe', `company` = 'XYZ-company-name', `first_name` = 'John', `last_name` = 'Doe', `prefix` = NULL, `suffix` = NULL, `title` = NULL, `created_at` = '2012-04-07 06:25:37', `updated_at` = '2012-04-07 06:25:37', `deleted_at` = NULL WHERE `contacts`.`id` = 314
```

Contact model looks like

```
acts_as_paranoid

has_friendly_id :full_name, :use_slug => true, :approximate_ascii => true, :allow_nil => true,
    :sequence_separator => '_', :max_length => 20
```

Now the scenario is if a new Contact with similar name is added and existing contact is paranoid then friendly_id is unable to find that record and creates a new slug with similar name, but Contact model wont accept it as that slug name is already present.

Is there a way to make friendly_id consider the paranoid records as well i.e. use something like

`scope => :with_deleted`

Comment: I am using acts_as_paranoid for Contact model along with friendly_id. Soft deleting a Contact deletes my slug record, which should not happen. Is there a way to avoid this dependency ?
How can I override Slug model ?

Comment: out of curiosity ... are you using friendly_id 3.x?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
yes using friendly_id 3.3.2 but I am now migrating to friendly_id 4.x
Thanks

Comment: Great! That will keep the :slug column in tact .. just be careful if you're using the historical module .. I would be curious to know how you go with this.

Comment: Thanks,
decided to fallback from the idea of migrating to friendly_id 4.x.
Though I found the actual cause that was throwing the exception. It was the destroy dependencies that I have used with polymorphic associations. So have to remove those dependencies and override the delete method.